# How to write the file number at every iteration in the loop?

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I want to write the file number at every iteration in my loop. I want to do this to restart the loop where I stop it. I'm trying something like this :

```
startfile=$1

for FILE in ./folder/*; do

if ! [ "$FILE" '=' "$next.num" ] ; then

perl -pi -e 's/"*.ext1"/"&.ext1"/g' ./file.txt ;
perl -pi -e 's/"*.ext2"/"&.ext2"/g' ./file.txt ;

let num="$FILE+1"

echo $num > next.num

    else
        echo Skipping $FILE
    fi

done
```

Comment: Your question lacks an ending, apparently.

Comment: The script doesn't work and I don't know how to make it works. The script has to loop 1 million files and the power will be lost before it ends. I want to restart it where it has stopped. So I'm trying to use the file number in directory, when the job is done, incrementing the number, where the job can restart.

Comment: Alright, go ahead and add that to your question.

Comment: Can you move the file after processing it?

Comment: So my question is, can you help me please to finish the script? Yes I can move the file after processing it.

Comment: `FILE` is a file name, not a number. Just increment `num`.

Comment: How to tell it to use the file number instead the file name to only use the `num` ?